# SQL syntax - to filter date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL output data.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| PymtDate  | ChkInDate | ChkOutDate| OtherDetails                          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2018-06-10| NULL      | NULL      | qqqqq                                 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2018-07-01| NULL      | NULL      | sssss                                 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2018-07-26|2019-02-10 |2018-08-10 | xxxxx                                 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2018-11-16|2019-01-29 |2018-12-29 | yyyyy                                 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2018-11-20|2019-01-01 |2019-01-01 | zzzzz                                 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2018-11-20|2019-01-02 |2019-01-01 | aaaaa                                 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It was generated from the following SQL.

```
select CONVERT(char(10), DatePayment, 120) PymtDate, CONVERT(char(10), DateCheckIn, 120) ChkInDate, CONVERT(char(10), DateCheckOut, 120) ChkOutDate, details as OtherDetails from details 
where PymtDate<= 'asAtDate' and 
ChkInDate>= DATEADD(DD,1,'asAtDate') or 
ChkOutDate>= DATEADD(DD,1,'asAtDate');
```

asAtDate in this case is 2018-12-31 for PymtDate.

The requirement is to remove all data in ChkInDate and ChkOutDate which is after the asAtDate (in this case after 2018-12-31). If I put AND at the where condition, it will remove data for ChkInDate & ChkOutDate that have NULL value.

the current SQL still display data 2018 from ChkOutDate .. and if ChkInDate got 2018 data.. it still show up.. because of the OR condition. How should I fix this? Please help.. thanks

BTW.. im using SQL Server Mgmt Studio. Edited the SQL to give better understanding.

My Expected results as follows:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| PymtDate  | ChkInDate | ChkOutDate| OtherDetails                          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2018-06-10| NULL      | NULL      | qqqqq                                 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2018-07-01| NULL      | NULL      | sssss                                 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2018-11-20|2019-01-01 |2019-01-01 | zzzzz                                 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2018-11-20|2019-01-02 |2019-01-01 | aaaaa                                 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please show the results that you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I edit my question and include the expected results..

Comment: Based on the comments below, and your answers, there seems to be some confusion with the data structures and parameters. Please edit your question and add the schema(s) of the source table(s) for the query. Be sure to include the index definitions as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
select Date1, Date2, Date3, details as OtherDetails from details 
where Date1 <= 'asAtDate' and 
(
  (Date3 > DATEADD(DD,1,'asAtDate') or Date3 is null) and 
  (Date2 > DATEADD(DD,1,'asAtDate') or Date2 is null)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this meet your requirements?

```
select Date1, Date2, Date3, details as OtherDetails from details 
where Date1 <= 'asAtDate' and 
    (Date3 > DATEADD(DD,1,'asAtDate') or Date2 > DATEADD(DD,1,'asAtDate'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want values *after* the asatdate, why not just do:

```
where Date1 <= @asAtDate and 
      (Date3 > @asAtDate or Date3 is null) and
      (Date2 > @asAtDate or Date2 is null)
```

I don't understand why you are adding a day to the value and then using `>`.

The use of `'asAtDate'` suggests (to me) that you are inserting the value directly into the query string.  That is a bad idea.  The `@asAtDate` instead suggests using parameters.

Comment: Sorry about that.. u are right.. i just need to use Date2 > @asAtDate.. But the checking for Date3 is null.. i got error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: the date data type is string which i get it from convert(char(10),Date1,120).. same goes to Date2 and Date3

Comment: @Julie . . . Don't convert dates to a string!  Pass the dates directly into the query.

Comment: and yes.. asAtDate is a parameter. Actually.. Date1, Date2, Date3 and asAtDate are all parameters.. sorry to make u confuse because I think it is because of the WHERE condition..

Comment: -,- its the problem created by previous programmer.. i don't know why he/she stored the value that way.. he even calculate and hard coded the SST/GST value inside the SQL which cause a lot of rounding issues =,=

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the SQL with the following.. It works perfectly..
Thank all for your comments and help. Really appreciate it.
Thanks again.

```
select CONVERT(char(10), DatePayment, 120) PymtDate, CONVERT(char(10), DateCheckIn, 120) ChkInDate, CONVERT(char(10), DateCheckOut, 120) ChkOutDate, details as OtherDetails from details 
where PymtDate <= 'asAtDate' and 
(isNull(ChkInDate,ChkOutDate) >= 'asAtDate' and ChkOutDate >= 'asAtDate');
```